# Method not found exception when using Semantic Kernel in an Azure Functions app

Tags: azure-functions, semantic-kernel

I created a sample Azure Functions app and tryin to use Semantic Kernel in it. It's a barebone app, the source code is in the GIT here: https://github.com/supreettare/CRUDNLPAzureFunction

I am running into this error

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddKeyedSingleton(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Object, System.Func`3<System.IServiceProvider,System.Object,!!0>)'.'
```

at this line when adding the AddAzureOpenAIChatCompletion to builder.services

```
var builder = Kernel.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddAzureOpenAIChatCompletion(azureOpenAIDeploymentName, azureOpenAIEndpoint, azureOpenAIAPIKey);
```

Any idea why this is happening and if there is a way to solve it?
Appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks to @gaurav-mantri sir, the reason could be the fact that we are using .Net 6 with this Azure Function & addkeyedsingleton is available in .Net 8 only. So did some further study on this & I understand in order to upgrade to .net8 I will also need to change my Azure function type from in -process to isolated worker type.  
As Isolated Worker Type only supports .net 8 as seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#supported-versions